# Replacement for AwsSignerExecutionAttribute from software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, spring-webflux

I have logic that signs reactive `ClientRequest` requests from Spring WebFlux.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMapAdapter
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.Aws4Signer
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsSignerExecutionAttribute
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionAttributes
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpFullRequest
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpMethod
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import java.util.function.Function

class WebClientAwsSigner(
    private val body: String? = null,
    private val signer: Aws4Signer,
    private val awsCredentialsProvider: AwsCredentialsProvider,
    private val serviceName: String,
    private val region: Region
) : Function<ClientRequest, Mono<ClientRequest>> {
    override fun apply(request: ClientRequest): Mono<ClientRequest> {
        val requestBuilder =
            SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
                .method(SdkHttpMethod.fromValue(request.method().name()))
                .uri(request.url())
                .apply {
                    if (body != null) {
                        contentStreamProvider { body.byteInputStream() }
                    }
                }
                .headers(request.headers())

        val attributes = ExecutionAttributes()
        attributes.putAttribute(
            AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.AWS_CREDENTIALS,
            awsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials()
        )
        attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SERVICE_SIGNING_NAME, serviceName)
        attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SIGNING_REGION, region)

        val signedAwsRequest = signer.sign(requestBuilder.build(), attributes)
        val signedClientRequest =
            ClientRequest.from(request)
                .headers {
                    it.clear()
                    it.addAll(MultiValueMapAdapter(signedAwsRequest.headers()))
                }
                .build()

        return Mono.just(signedClientRequest)
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that `AwsSignerExecutionAttribute` is deprecated.

How do I sign a request in AWS auth SDK that can later be passed to a reactive request?

Comment: Are you using execution interceptors or not? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ExecutionAttribute`, use [`Aws4SignerParams`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/signer/params/Aws4SignerParams.html).

So replace:

```kotlin
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsSignerExecutionAttribute
...

val attributes = ExecutionAttributes()
attributes.putAttribute(
    AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.AWS_CREDENTIALS,
    awsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials()
)
attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SERVICE_SIGNING_NAME, serviceName)
attributes.putAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SIGNING_REGION, region)

val signedAwsRequest = signer.sign(requestBuilder.build(), attributes)
```

With:

```kotlin
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.Aws4SignerParams
...

val attributes = Aws4SignerParams.builder()
    .awsCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials())
    .signingName(serviceName)
    .signingRegion(region)
    .build();

val signedAwsRequest = signer.sign(requestBuilder.build(), attributes)
```